# In raid 10 if the sizes of pairs are same, can pairs be different sizes?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have two 2TB drives, 2 1TB drives and 2 750Gb drives I would like to use the six drives in a raid 10 array and hope that the full capicity of all drives can be utilized with Windows Home Server 2011
I don't see a post for Windows Home Server 2011.

Answer (score 3):

Short Answer: Yes.

Long Answer:

Raid 10 is really Raid 1+0, that is a Stripe across Mirrored Pairs. In any raid configuration above RAID 0 (which realistically and in the wild is just 1,5,6 since RAID levels above those are just combinations of the previous RAID levels) require that you have matching capacities. RAID 0 dos *not* have this requirement since it really isn't RAID at all and is just combining a bunch of disks to form a larger disk.

So, to summarize: As long as your mirrors are matching capacities you can stripe across mirrors of different sizes.

Answer (score 1):

you can, as the blocks are striped across all the pairs.

however, it will be n x miminum pair size, where n is the number of pairs, because the smallest pair will stop the striping process, and you will then waste all the space in larger pairs, if you don't mind.